# Open filetype (xml) with clickonce application

Tags: c#, .net, registry, clickonce, windows-shell

I have a clickonce application that is available offline and online. It is used to open and edit .xml files. It can open .xml files if their path is given as startup argument like

```
"c:Path\Name.appref-ms" "Xmlpath\name.xml"
```

using the console window.

Now i want to add a registry entry, so i can rightclick any .xml and find my application under  **open with**. I added a key under *HKCR\.xml\OpenWithProgids* and a key *HKCR\myapp.xml\shell\open\command* but i cant figure out, how to make that command. My understanding is, that the command should be the same as the one i can use in console window, so i tried

```
"c:Path\Name.appref-ms" "%1"
```

This does not seem to work though, I also tried a lot of different uses of quotationmarks but always get

```
name.xml is not a valid win 32 application
```

as error message. Does anyone know, if what I want to do is possible and how to do it?

---

Additional Info:
 - if i use the executable file it works, just can't seem to do it with the clickonce thingy

- the application uses the argument like this:

```
if(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData!=null)
{ 
    //Do something 
}
```

Comment: I have solved this issue in one of my private applications. If you don't want to waste time and can wait until I get home - about 90 minutes from now - I'll post a working answer for you :)

Comment: @Herdo thank you, take your time, your help is much apprechiated :)

Comment: No problem. Just one question: The `"executable file it works"` - you mean the registered file type associated with the ClickOnce application?

Comment: executable file like in "myapp.exe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is the result, how the shell extension can look like (greyed out the other extensions):
[image]

You need to add a few entries into the registry. I wrote a registry helper class for it. You might either use this, or just apply the keys. You only need to adjust the names and call the method `EnsureRegistryKeyIntegrity()`. Note: I added a configuration switch to enable or disable the shell extension feature. This might be usefull if you don't want to blow up your shell to much.

One **important** thing: You need to run the method with administrator privileges, otherwise you will receive an exception.

```
internal static class RegistryHelper
{
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    #region Statics

    /// <summary>
    /// A dictionary of registry roots and their subkeys to handle.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly Dictionary<RegistryHive, string[]> RegistryKeys = new Dictionary<RegistryHive, string[]>
    {
        {
            RegistryHive.ClassesRoot,
            new []
            {
                @"*\shell\QuickHash",
                @"*\shell\QuickHash\command",
                @"Directory\shell\QuickHash",
                @"Directory\shell\QuickHash\command"
            }
        }
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// The registry default value for the command keys.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly string RegistryCommandValue;

    #endregion

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    #region Constructors

    static RegistryHelper()
    {
        RegistryCommandValue = String.Format("\"{0}\" /file \"%1\"", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    }

    #endregion

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Ensures that all required registry keys exist and adjusts their values if required.
    /// </summary>
    public static void EnsureRegistryKeyIntegrity()
    {
        foreach (var registryRoot in RegistryKeys.Keys)
        {
            foreach (var registryKeyName in RegistryKeys[registryRoot])
            {
                if (((App)Application.Current).Config.EnableExplorerContextMenu)
                {
                    var regKey = GetOrAddKey(registryRoot, registryKeyName);
                    AdjustKey(regKey);
                    regKey.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    DeleteKey(registryRoot, registryKeyName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    #region Private Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or adds a specific key for a specific registry root.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="registryRoot">The registry root.</param>
    /// <param name="registryKeyName">The registry key.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the gotten or added registry key.</returns>
    private static RegistryKey GetOrAddKey(RegistryHive registryRoot, string registryKeyName)
    {
        switch (registryRoot)
        {
            case RegistryHive.ClassesRoot:
                return Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(registryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.SetValue) ??
                       Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(registryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
            case RegistryHive.CurrentUser:
                return Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(registryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.SetValue) ??
                       Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(registryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
            case RegistryHive.LocalMachine:
                return Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.SetValue) ??
                       Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(registryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
            case RegistryHive.Users:
                return Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(registryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.SetValue) ??
                       Registry.Users.CreateSubKey(registryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
            case RegistryHive.PerformanceData:
                return Registry.PerformanceData.OpenSubKey(registryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.SetValue) ??
                       Registry.PerformanceData.CreateSubKey(registryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
            case RegistryHive.CurrentConfig:
                return Registry.CurrentConfig.OpenSubKey(registryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.SetValue) ??
                       Registry.CurrentConfig.CreateSubKey(registryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
            case RegistryHive.DynData:
                // DynData is obsolete
                return Registry.PerformanceData.OpenSubKey(registryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.SetValue) ??
                       Registry.PerformanceData.CreateSubKey(registryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("registryRoot");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes an unused registry key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="registryRoot">The registry root.</param>
    /// <param name="registryKeyName">The registry key.</param>
    private static void DeleteKey(RegistryHive registryRoot, string registryKeyName)
    {
        const string missingRightsText = "You don't have the permissions to perform this action.";
        const string missingRightsCaption = "Error";
        try
        {
            switch (registryRoot)
            {
                case RegistryHive.ClassesRoot:
                    Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKeyTree(registryKeyName, false);
                    break;
                case RegistryHive.CurrentUser:
                    Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKeyTree(registryKeyName, false);
                    break;
                case RegistryHive.LocalMachine:
                    Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKeyTree(registryKeyName, false);
                    break;
                case RegistryHive.Users:
                    Registry.Users.DeleteSubKeyTree(registryKeyName, false);
                    break;
                case RegistryHive.PerformanceData:
                    Registry.PerformanceData.DeleteSubKeyTree(registryKeyName, false);
                    break;
                case RegistryHive.CurrentConfig:
                    Registry.CurrentConfig.DeleteSubKeyTree(registryKeyName, false);
                    break;
                case RegistryHive.DynData:
                    // DynData is obsolete
                    Registry.PerformanceData.DeleteSubKeyTree(registryKeyName, false);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("registryRoot");
            }
        }
        catch (SecurityException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(missingRightsText, missingRightsCaption, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(missingRightsText, missingRightsCaption, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adjusts the registry keys value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="regKey">The registry key to adjust.</param>
    private static void AdjustKey(RegistryKey regKey)
    {
        if (regKey.Name.EndsWith("QuickHash"))
        {
            SetExplorerShellName(regKey);
            SetExplorerShellIcon(regKey);
            return;
        }
        if (regKey.Name.EndsWith("command"))
        {
            var keyDefaultValue = regKey.GetValue("") as String;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyDefaultValue)
             || keyDefaultValue != RegistryCommandValue)
            {
                regKey.SetValue(null, RegistryCommandValue, RegistryValueKind.String);
            }
            return;
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException("Given registry key is not supported.");
    }

    private static void SetExplorerShellName(RegistryKey regKey)
    {
        const string quickHashDisplayName = "Quick Hash";
        var keyDefaultValue = regKey.GetValue("") as String;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyDefaultValue)
            || keyDefaultValue != quickHashDisplayName)
        {
            regKey.SetValue(null, quickHashDisplayName, RegistryValueKind.String);
        }
    }

    private static void SetExplorerShellIcon(RegistryKey regKey)
    {
        var executingAssembly = (new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
        regKey.SetValue("Icon", String.Format("{0},0", executingAssembly));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but sadly it didn't work. I still get the same error. I think I will try some variations of your approach, maybe i can figure something out. Still, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Pasoe Can you please post the registry entry/entries generated by the code?

Comment: whoops, I screwed up. Your Solution did work, I was still using ActivationData instead of string[] args

Comment: This is even better than I expected it to be :)

Comment: @Pasoe Ok. I think the `/file` part was for an internal handling. So I could distinguish between a file start via the ClickOnce file association and the file opening via the windows shell. I'm glad that it's working :)